# Pyramid/butterfly plot?

Tags: plotting, visualization

I'm trying to do a plot like one below. I found a recipe for R in the question below, but wondering if there's something similar in Mathematica, any suggestions?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499837/how-to-plot-a-butterfly-plot-or-symmetric-barchart-in-r

[image]

Comment: This is called [`PairedBarChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PairedBarChart.html).

Comment: ...or `PairedHistogram`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use two `BarChart`s for left and right wings of the butterfly correspondingly. Then combine them by `Show`. Option `BarOrigin` defines the direction of the bars grow.

```
c1 = BarChart[rightwing, BarOrigin -> Left];
c2 = BarChart[leftwing, BarOrigin -> Right];
Show[c1,c2]
```